# Why do deep-friction treatments stimulate fibroblast activity and collagen production?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons, physiotherapy, massage, collagen

{1} presents some techniques to treat tendinopathies, and says that:

> deep-friction treatments serve to stimulate fibroblast activity and collagen production.

Why do deep-friction treatments stimulate fibroblast activity and collagen production?

I am mostly interested in epicondylopathies (medial or lateral, i.e., tennis elbows and golfer elbows)

---

- {1} Bass, Lmt Evelyn. “Tendinopathy: Why the Difference Between Tendinitis and Tendinosis Matters.” International Journal of Therapeutic Massage & Bodywork: Research, Education, & Practice 5.1 (2012) https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3312643/